# Iterate through the finite groups in MAGMA

Tags: computer-algebra-systems, magma-cas

How may I iterate over the finite groups in MAGMA of orders between $1$ and $N$ (where possible), and compute a given property of them?

Comment: A kind of answer can be given for SAGE [here](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Abstract_and_Geometric_Algebra/Abstract_Algebra%3A_Theory_and_Applications_(Judson)/09%3A_Isomorphisms/9.05%3A_Sage)

Comment: Word of advice, you almost never want to do a "for every group of order 1 to N" directly. Try to reduce the search space as much as possible, removing any orders that you know to be impossible, especially powers of 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magma has a database of small groups, see http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/777:

> Small Groups: This database is constructed by Hans Ulrich Besche, Heiko Dietrich, Bettina Eick, Eamonn O'Brien, and Eileen Pan [BE99a], [BEO01], [BE99b], [O'B90], [BE01], [O'B91], [MNVL04], [OVL05], [DE05], [DEP22], and contains the following groups:
>
> - All groups of order up to 2000, excluding the groups of order 1024.
> - The groups whose order is the product of at most 4 primes.
> - The groups of order dividing p^7 for p a prime.
> - The groups of order 3^8.
> - The groups of order q^n p, where q^n is a prime-power dividing 2^8, 3^6, 5^5 or 7^4 and p is a prime different to q.
> - The groups of square-free order.

You should be able to use the function `SmallGroups(S: parameters) : [RngIntElt] -> [* Grp *]` for your purposes, e.g.

```
for grp in SmallGroups([ 1 .. N ]) do
    // compute some property
end for;
```

If you are only after the groups satisfying a given property, there is a nice example of that about half-way down this page in the Magma handbook http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/779.